# Adding SSO teammate to multiple sub users in Twilio sendgrid

Tags: sendgrid

I have a parent account in Sendgrid. I have created 2 sub users. One for each environment (Dev and Test). Each sub user has its own API Key for sending emails.
Now when i try to onboard users i am trying to use SSO Teammate. But when i add the teammate (already in Dev) to Test sub user, its throwing an error

> The email you are assigning as the SSO Teammate's username already belongs to an existing user. You will need to delete the conflicting user or modify the existing username so that this SSO teammate can be created.

But the teammate's id is only added to another sub user(Dev). Its not there in the parent account. Is this a wrong way of handling teammates in SendGrid?
Basically we want to separate users in each environment and provide them different access in each sub user (account)